# Outlook 2007 starts with minimized window

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Outlook 2007, starts at boot, minimized: suddenly, as of 2 weeks ago, when I click on the taskbar icon (Outlook already started but minimized) what opens on screen is a tiny "window" the size of the close-minimize-restore buttons.

I then have to move it down the screen, and drag the borders to bring it to full size, or, sometimes, clicking on the restore button maximizes the tiny window: then, for days, it starts either the same way or in some other small size, not the same as I left it.

I would appreciate suggestions on  how to repair this particular example of Outlook not remembering its setting?

win7, 64 bit.  outlook 2007 32 bit

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue when my outlook was set to run in minimized mode.

Can you check if you have the same problem by running through the following steps:-

1. Close all open instances of Outlook.
2. Click Start > All Program Files > Microsoft Office
3. Locate Microsoft Outlook, right click it and choose Properties.
4. In the open box, click Shortcut tab. After Run, check if minimized if selected. If it is selected, select maximized.
5. Click OK to save the changes.
6. Start Outlook from Start > All Program Files > Microsoft Office > Microsoft Outlook again.

P.S - With Step 3. You only locate the the instance of Outlook with which you are experiencing the issue.

Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

Open Outlook and maximize the program. Then close Outlook correctly, using the menu option: *File-> Exit*. After reopening Outlook it should be maximized, as it should remember its last state. (If it isn't, there is something else wrong and you can try using [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/) to clear the [Window size/Location cache](http://www.piriform.com/docs/ccleaner/ccleaner-rules/windows-tab/advanced-windows-files).)

If it did remember its previous state, size it the way you want it to be and minimize it to the tray as you had it, close the program as before and restart to see if it took effect.

Comment: maximized, closed using file>exit.  didn'thelp.  cleared window size/locatoin cache with ccleaner.  also, didn't help.

Comment: tried shift key.  didn't help.  thanks, though.  i am realizing that the tiny window is the "restored down" state. if window is maximized and i click the "restore down " button, i get the tiny window. outlook is automatically opening to the restored down state, rather than the last used size.

Comment: sorry, about formatting of comment.  enter key doesn't seem to work on this forum, instead it automatically adds the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Resize it, and hold the shift key down while closing it. Then re-open it. Not sure about here, but this works for many Microsoft products.

Answer (score 0):

Not a straight problem solver. You could create shortcut to Outlook and set it to open in maximized state.

Comment: yes, that will give outlook, opened maximized on screen. but what i am trying to get is outlook starting up, out of the way, accessible when i ask for it, in a full sized window.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 7, an excellent shortcut for this is to hold down the Windows key + the left or right arrow button. This will automatically resize the window to fit in the left or right half  of your screen. From there, the maximize button should be easy to spot.

This is also very useful for multi-monitor setups, I use a monitor with my laptop and sometimes after unplugging my external monitor, I leave an orphaned window behind, stuck where the external monitor used to be. Highlighting it and pushing the Windows key plus the left/right arrow brings it back to my main screen.

Comment: Wont windows + up be better? Maximise directly?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve this issue:

1. Open Outlook
2. Open Task Manager
3. Right click on Outlook and select maximise.
4. This will open the Outlook on full screen.
5. Close Task Manager.
6. Outlook will open as normal.

I hope this helps.